# Query to list Users with "nologin" privilege in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I get a list of users in Postgres that do not have privilege to login?

I am using the following query to list the users and the groups they are part of

```sql
     SELECT usename AS role_name,
            CASE
                WHEN usesuper AND usecreatedb THEN
                    CAST('superuser, create database' AS pg_catalog.text)
                WHEN usesuper THEN
                    CAST('superuser' AS pg_catalog.text)
                WHEN usecreatedb THEN
                    CAST('create database' AS pg_catalog.text)
                ELSE
                    CAST('' AS pg_catalog.text)
            END role_attributes
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_user
        ORDER BY role_name desc;
```

which I believe is same as running `\du` in `psql`.

Answer (score 2):

I figured the above query lists only users that can login, but we can find that login info from a column named `rolcanlogin` in `pg_catalog.pg_roles`

Comment: Correct. Users are roles with the login privilege. From the documentation: `As explained in Chapter 22, PostgreSQL actually does privilege management in terms of “roles”. In this chapter, we consistently use database user to mean “role with the LOGIN privilege”.` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/client-authentication.html

Answer (score 0):

The underlying sql from `\du` is the query below. That should provide you with the information which users have privileges to login and which do not.

```
SELECT r.rolname, r.rolsuper, r.rolinherit,
  r.rolcreaterole, r.rolcreatedb, r.rolcanlogin,
  r.rolconnlimit, r.rolvaliduntil,
  ARRAY(SELECT b.rolname
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m
        JOIN pg_catalog.pg_roles b ON (m.roleid = b.oid)
        WHERE m.member = r.oid) as memberof
, r.rolreplication
, r.rolbypassrls
FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles r
WHERE r.rolname !~ '^pg_'
ORDER BY 1;
```